# Swift Realm - "Value of type 'Results' has no member"

Tags: ios, swift, database, xcode, realm

I am trying to get the data from a RealmDB and filter by id. As the Realm Documentation suggests (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries) I am using:

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let Result = realm.objects(DBName.self).filter("ID == %@", id)
```

XCode doesn't show any warning or errors in these two lines, but when a try to use the results by doing this:

```
    print(Result.ID)
```

Even having the ID field in the database a get the error:
`Value of type 'Results<DBName>' has no member 'ID'`. And I also can't access any other field.

Comment: I see there is an accepted answer but going forward, be careful of naming as it can lead to confusion. With this code `realm.objects(DBName.self)` the DBName *isn't* a database name, it's an *Object* name. Like a Person or Dog object. So this would be more clear code `realm.objects(PersonObject.self)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
realm.objects(DBName.self).filter("ID == %@", id)
```

This returns all the `DBName` objects whose `ID` is `id` in a `Results`[[doc]](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Structs/Results.html). So, the returned value is a list of objects. That is why the error says `'Results<DBName>' has no member 'ID'`.

If you are 100% sure you have one object in there, you can try to retrieve the first element this way. (For production, you should always use `guard` statement to prevent a crash as Jay suggests in the comment section.)

```swift
realm.objects(DBName.self).filter("ID == %@", id).first!
```

Or, if your `ID` is a primary key, you can do this.

```swift
realm.object(ofType: DBName.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
```

Comment: @renanlopes Just a quick minor point `.first!` is dangerous as it's explicitly unwrapping an optional, which may be nil which could cause code to crash. Understanding that you mention 'if you are sure'. `guard let firstResult = realm.objects(DBName.self).filter("ID == %@", id).first {` would be a safer option.